# How can I fix the scaling optimization pytorch code error

Tags: pytorch

I want make a scaling optimization system

```
class GraphFit:
  def __init__(self):
    self.X=torch.tensor([])
    self.Y=torch.tensor([])

    self.scale_x=torch.Tensor([])
    self.scale_y=torch.Tensor([])

    self.opt=0
  
  def scale(self,imagx=1.,imagy=1):
    self.scale_x=torch.tensor([1.],requires_grad=True)
    self.scale_y=torch.tensor([1.],requires_grad=True)

    self.X=self.scale_x *self.X
    self.Y=self.scale_y *self.Y

  def optimize(self,lr=1e-03):
    params=[self.scale_x,self.scale_y]
    self.opt=torch.optim.Adam(params,lr)    
  


    


x=torch.linspace(-10,10,100)
 
yt=0.5*torch.sin(0.2 * x)   ##truth 

y=torch.sin(x)   ## try

G1=GraphFit()
G1.X=x

G1.scale()    

G1.optimize()

L=nn.MSELoss()


for i in range(1):  ####
  G1.opt.zero_grad() 
  G1.Y=torch.sin(G1.X)
  err=L(G1.Y,yt)
  err.backward()
  G1.opt.step()

  if i%100==0:
    print(err)

print(G1.scale_y.grad,G1.scale_x.grad)
```

When I use  'for i in range(1)' , its output is

```
tensor(0.1189, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
None tensor([-0.0425])
```

and when I use 'for i in range(N)' for N >1

it's output is

```
---> 83   err.backward()

Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

########################

dummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummy
dummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummy
dummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummy
dummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummydummy

Comment: try replacing `err.backward()` with `err.backward(retain_graph=True)`

Comment: It works, but the loss does not go down..